# Adding Context to Spring Boot Embedded Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

Is it possible to add a context to Spring Boot's embedded tomcat that can access the filesystem?

I'm trying to get the same functionality as adding `<Context docBase="/path/to/my/files" path="/MyFiles"/>` where the context is used for directly viewing/downloading files.

In Spring Boot I've managed to add a context with the following:

```
@Bean
public ServletWebServerFactory factory() {
    return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
        @Override
        protected TomcatWebServer getTomcatWebServer(Tomcat tomcat) {
            tomcat.addContext("/MyFiles", "/path/to/my/files");
            return super.getTomcatWebServer(tomcat);
        }
    };      
}
```

However this context is only created/restricted to where Spring Boot puts the running tomcat in /private/var/folders/zy/T. Therefore any requests to that context just return a 404 because the file I'm asking for doesn't exists in /private/var...etc.

Is there any way to create the Tomcat context so that it has access to files elsewhere on the system?

Comment: Are you using Spring MVC?  Because it has important repercussions for where you can put static files by default.

Comment: Static files such as css, js, and images are all working fine.
My issue is with accessing files that are elsewhere in the file system.

For example, if I have a tomcat installation, I'm able to edit server.xml and manually add a context so that navigating to localhost:8080/MyFiles serves the directory /My/Files off the file system. This is not currently possible with SpringBoot. I've succeeded in making the new context, however it serves the content as if the root is not the root of the file system but rather the root of wherever SpringBoot creates its temporary tomcat server.